# creating fade between 2 videos in winforms

Tags: vb.net, winforms

i have a media player in vb form...with 2 files in a listbox as a playlist

now i want to create a fade between changing these files as a transition how can i do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with the `MediaPlayer` control, unless you "fake" it by merging the two videos into one (handling the overlap transition from the first to the second in your code) and then playing the single merged video.

DirectShow can do this in theory, but programming DirectShow is difficult (all the more so from .Net) and it's obscure enough now that you won't find many people to help you.  Also, from my experiments into this area (I was trying to use DirectShow to transition from one video w/sound to the next without any interruption or slight pausing), it appears that DirectShow can play one video at a time with no problems at all, but on some systems (including mine) it can't handle playing two at once.  To do a cross-fade transition, you need to have both graphs running during the overlap time, which my computer at least was never able to handle.

I would check out WPF and see if its controls can do this.  I'm not sure they can but it's possible.